# $PYTHONPATH changes when using Gunicorn and virtualenv

Tags: python, nginx, flask, virtualenv, gunicorn

I am working on an app with Flask mounted at Gunicorn and nginx. To do this I had to use a virtual environment for my python Flask program, which I have in a root directory, let's call it `test/`, and the code is in `test.py`. I have configured the necessary PYTHONPATH and PATH environmental variables from outside the `venv` in order to use my modules. They seem to be okay. **The problem is**: that when I use Gunicorn to execute `test.py`, the PYTHONPATH (the path I get with `sys.path`) seems to be overwritten and I do not have any idea to fix it. The PYTHONPATH is already defined with the necessary directories from before. When I activate the virtualenv, the PYTHONPATH remains the same, as I wanted. But, when I use gunicorn (which uses the same virtualenv), the PYTHONPATH gets overwritten. I want to know why is this overwritten and how to prevent it.

Output of the upstart log `/var/log/upstart/test.log`, which is a log file for the execution of `test.py`. The `PROJ_LAST` paths I configured are gone.

```
2017-01-05 08:14:48 [7296] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2017-01-05 08:14:48 [7296] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (7296)
2017-01-05 08:14:48 [7296] [INFO] Using worker: socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker
2017-01-05 08:14:48 [7300] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7300
Result of command 'print sys.path'
['/home/myuser/test', '/home/myuser/test/venv/bin',
'/home/myuser/test/venv/lib/python2.7',
'/home/myuser/test/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/home/myuser/test/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/home/myuser/test/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/home/myuser/test/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/home/myuser/test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', 
'/home/myuser/CURRENTLY_MOD/otheruser/acs-ria/trunk/PROJ/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/API']
Result of command 'print sys.executable'
/home/myuser/test/venv/bin/python
```

Here the upstart. `wsgi.py` is a kind of entry point for the app:

```
myuser@PROJcontrol:/etc/init$ cat test.conf
description "Gunicorn application server running test.py"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid myuser
setgid www-data

env PATH=/home/myuser/test/venv/bin
chdir /home/myuser/test
exec gunicorn --worker-class socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker --timeout 200 wsgi:app
```

But when I try to read the PYTHONPATH or the PATH when the virtualenv is activated, the result is as follows (the result I want!):

```
myuser@PROJcontrol:~/test/venv/bin$ source activate
(venv)myuser@PROJcontrol:~/test/venv/bin$ echo $PATH
/home/myuser/test/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
(venv)myuser@PROJcontrol:~/test/venv/bin$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/clients/PROJ_client:/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/Icefiles:/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/API:/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/observingModes/
(venv)myuser@PROJcontrol:~/test/venv/bin$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 20:00:17)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/clients/PROJ_client',
'/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/Icefiles',
'/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/API',
'/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/observingModes',
'/home/myuser/test/venv/lib/python2.7',
'/home/myuser/test/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/home/myuser/test/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/home/myuser/test/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/home/myuser/test/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/home/myuser/test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
'/home/myuser/CURRENTLY_MOD/otheruser/acs-ria/trunk/PROJ/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/API',
'/home/myuser/test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

The virtualenv venv folder is located together with `test.py`. The `bin/activate` file is untouched.

Here attached some interesting environmental variables:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
CURRENT_BASE=/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src
PWD=/home/myuser/test
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PS1=\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/myuser
CURRENT_OBS=/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/observingModes
PYTHONPATH=/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/clients/PROJ_client:/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/Icefiles:/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/API:/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/observingModes/
LOGNAME=myuser
CURRENT_PROJ=/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/API
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.0.4 55163 192.168.0.97 22
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
WIP_PROJ=/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/clients/PROJ_client:/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/Icefiles:/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/API:/home/myuser/PROJ_LAST/ria/TCS/rpiPROJ/src/observingModes/
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

If you need some additional information, please don't hesitate to ask me. I would be glad if someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install the packages? Did you use `pip` at all? Remember `sys.path` is just a normal Python list. You can try manually adding the missing paths.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying is wrong with your paths, but I also don't understand at all what you are doing. The *whole point* of a virtualenv is that it changes your PYTHONPATH. So why are you trying to modify it manually?

Comment: @Eddie I installed all the packages using pip. Yes, I understand that `sys.path` is a list, but I still do not see any reason for it to be modified somehow when I use gunicorn.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The PYTHONPATH is already defined with the necessary directories. When I activate the virtualenv, the PYTHONPATH remains the same, as I wanted. But, when I use gunicorn (which uses the same virtualenv), the PYTHONPATH gets overwritten. I want to know why is this overwritten and how to prevent it.

Comment: Where are you configuring gunicorn to run in the virtualenv?

Comment: @DanielRoseman at `test.conf`, exactly when I wrote: `env PATH=/home/myuser/test/venv/bin`. Also, in the gunicorn log (`test.log`) is possible to see that gunicorn is running with the venv: `Result of command 'print sys.executable'
/home/myuser/test/venv/bin/python`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still not following what you are trying to do. Your upstart configuration sets the Python executable only. But I can't see anywhere that you set the "other" paths that you think should be there.